# Fantasy book prince runs away to find his mother, encounters maid with cobwebs under her eyelids

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I'm looking for a book I read years ago.

A boy or prince is in search for his mother. He is neither strong nor brave, so runs away. His older male cousin joins him.

They encounter a young maiden who appears blind and crippled, but in fact has cobwebs packed under her eyelids and has dislocated her ankle so that she isn't preyed upon by men. She leads them to the crone.

It has a maiden, mother, crone theme. Mother turns out to be trapped in ice, to prevent her from healing the Earth?

Gaelic or celtic themes maybe?

Answer (score -1):

The Lost Runes by Jane Welch (???)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please can you [edit] your answer to add some more details about this book and how it fits the description in the question? As it stands, it's impossible to judge whether it's right or wrong. See also [our guidance on answering story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/31394).